# Extending an application and accessing its functions

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, inversion-of-control

I'm trying to design a lightweight service that performs scheduled tasks.  Since I want to be able to slowly add new\different tasks, I've been reading a lot about reflection and Inversion of Control\Dependency injection.  With all the different options and frameworks though, I'm lost in the simplest question:  How to I access new functions so they can be executed?

Comment: By reflection, of course.

Comment: Your question is probably not specific enough: **1.** How do you want to extend the service? By simply editing the source code, recompiling, and restarting it; or by putting additional DLLs in the service's binary directory; or by changing its configuration files? **2.** Perhaps an answer to #1 will help explain why you think Reflection or IoC will be helpful in this case. **3.** Perhaps a small (even non-working) code example for your attempts to execute a "new function" would help explain what you're trying to do. **4.** "new function": .NET is object-oriented. Usually, you add new classes…

Answer (score 0):

Most design/patterns for adding extensibility to application and frameworks based on them encourage, even sometimes force us to use **well-defined interfaces** in parts we need to extend the application, so its all about Unified interfaces, **accessing new functions should be done through these well-defined interfaces**, managing and calling new methods and execution flow should be considered internal implementation of the plugin/extension.

so I believe the first step would be to find requirements and unified them as an extension point, after that its simply about implementing extensions based on framework of choice.